# Can a quadcopter fly stable while its all 4 motors from different manufacturers?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, quadcopter

What if we used 4 motors which all are from different manufacturers? Will it fly/hover ? All 4 brushless motors have same kv and dimensions. Like 2204 2300kv .

Comment: I would think it would depend more on the output power than manufacturer or dimensions...

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem except the tuning of the control loop might be difficult

Comment: You might get more practical answers on a site like rc groups dot com.